# How to set top align for tabular inside tabular?

Tags: tables

My source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For removing number order at section header.
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
\makeatother

% For font-size header
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}

% For top-align and left-align size.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
 
 % Define tab length.
 \newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}


\title{\textbf{\large{CURRICULUM VITAE}}}
\author{\textbf{\textit{Do Van Vy}}}
\date{July 2016}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{BASIC INFORMATION}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Full name & \textit{Do Van Vy}\\
Date of birth & \textit{26\textsuperscript{th} August 1997}\\
Hometown/Residence & \textit{Cat Que - Hoai Duc - Hanoi, Vietnam}\\
Marital status & \textit{Single}\\
Email & \textit{dovanvy@outlook.com}\\
Mobile number & \textit{+84 90 323 4523}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
&
\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{vy2.png}
\hline
\end{tabular}



\section{HIGHER EDUCATION}
\textbf{Vietnam Forestry University}\\
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Address:&Xuan Mai town - Chuong My district - Hanoi\\
Type:&Full-time\\
Major:&Agro-forestry\\
Result:&Average-good\\
Academic year:&2005 - 2009\\
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{Hanoi University of Science and Technology}\\
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
Address:&No. 1 - Dai Co Viet street - Hai Ba Trung district - Hanoi\\
Type:&Full-time\\
Major:&Information Technology\\
Result:&Good\\
Academic year:&2012 - 2015\\
\end{tabular}
\bigskip


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{vy2.png}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:univerise}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Help me put text section at vertical-top or vertical-center position. Thank you!

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[t]{...}`? `\begin{tabular}[c]{...`?

Comment: `minipage`s would work better than a `tabular` here.

Answer (score 1):

I propose another code, without `multirow`: as the picture is the only cell in its column,a simple `\smash{\raisebox…` will do the trick. I've added a variant, without vertical rules, and the thicker horizontal rules of `booktabs`, which looks nicer in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% For removing number order at section header.
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
\makeatother

% For font-size header
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}

% For top-align and left-align size.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

% Define tab length.
 \newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}


\title{\textbf{\large{CURRICULUM VITAE}}}
\author{\textbf{\textit{Do Nhu Vy}}}
\date{July 2016}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{BASIC INFORMATION}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|>{\itshape}l|l|}
\hline
Full name & Do Nhu Vy & \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height +1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sendak}} \\
Date of birth & 26\textsuperscript{th} August 1987 & \\
Hometown/Residence & Cat Que -- Hoai Duc -- Hanoi, Vietnam & \\
Marital status & Single & \\
Email & donhuvy@hotmail.com & \\
Skype & dnv2006 & \\
Mobile number & +84 90 323 7207 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\section{BASIC INFORMATION}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}>{\textcolor{CadetBlue3}{\textbullet}\enspace}l>{\itshape}ll@{}}
\toprule
Full name & Do Nhu Vy & \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sendak}} \\
Date of birth & 26\textsuperscript{th} August 1987 & \\
Hometown/Residence & Cat Que -- Hoai Duc -- Hanoi, Vietnam & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just came across your answer. I'd love to get to read a resume illustrated with pictures of Max and the Wild Things... :-)

Comment: @Mico: Me too… Or Pepe le Pew…